# Project Page without User Page possible

Tags: github-pages

Can a project page like `http(s)://<username>.github.io/<projectname>`, exist without a user page, `http(s)://<username>.github.io`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It only seems necessary to wait a bit until it starts running.